# jQuery Smooth Zoom Effect

Tags: jquery

I am expecting a smooth zoom effect just like this:

http://www.twoixter.com/experiments/jquery-growshrink

I am not able to achieve this effect. Please help.

Comment: What have you tried? What issues have you faced? Why are you not able to use that code?

Comment: zoom effect using css3 transform is pretty smooth

Comment: ALL CAPS WON'T WIN YOU ANY FAVOURS ON STACKOVERFLOW. Please stop shouting

Comment: I tried to use the same popup animation in the above link but after saving the page I am not able to use that can u help me to do that

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to import all necessary libraries necessary for the plugin to run, such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Comment: I have Imported all the files but still it is not happening other than popup everything is coming